# Hypothesis search strategy for dictionaries with different types of values

Tags: python, dictionary, python-hypothesis

I am trying to generate dictionaries containing different python types as values using the hypothesis module.

For lists I can do this simply using the expression

```py
from hypothesis import given
import hypothesis.strategies as st

@given(
    st.lists(
        st.from_type(type)
            .flatmap(st.from_type)
            .filter(lambda x: not isinstance(x, (type(None)))),
        min_size=2,
        unique_by=lambda x: type(x),
    )
)
def test_something(dictionary):
    ...
```

which gives me `[int, str, ...]` (different python type for each entry).
But for dictionaries, I there is no `unique_by` for the values.

```py
@given(
    st.dictionaries(
        st.text(min_size=1, max_size=10),
        st.from_type(type).flatmap(st.from_type)
            .filter(lambda x: not isinstance(x, (type(None), bool))),
        min_size=2,
    )
)
def test_something(dictionary):
    ...
```

which results in e.g. `{'a': int, 'b': int, ...}` → the type of value is the same for all entries.

Is there an easy way to generate `{'a': int, 'b': str, ..}` (at least two different python types in `dict.values()`)?

Comment: do you need a strategy that will generate dictionaries with values of unique type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can reuse your initial approach using the fact that `dict`s can be built from key-value pairs like

```py
from hypothesis import given, strategies as st


@given(st.builds(zip,
                 st.lists(st.text(min_size=1, max_size=10),
                          min_size=2,
                          unique=True),
                 st.lists(st.from_type(type)
                          .flatmap(st.from_type)
                          .filter(lambda x: not isinstance(x, (type(None)))),
                          min_size=2,
                          unique_by=lambda x: type(x),
                          ))
       .map(dict))
def test_something(dictionary):
    values_types = list(map(type, dictionary.values()))

    assert len(set(values_types)) == len(values_types)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, it is what I need. I completely forgot about creating dictionaries this way - although I only seen it a few days earlier in the hypothesis code :D.
I will mark this answer as the correct one as the test stats are better:
```
 - 100 passing examples, 0 failing examples, 7 invalid examples (seen up to 25)
  - Typical runtimes: 1-18 ms (sometimes faster)
  - Fraction of time spent in data generation: ~ 97%
  - Stopped because settings.max_examples=100
  - Events:
    * 78.50%, Retried draw from sampled_from
```

Answer (score 2):

As Azat Ibrakov mentions, you can build this up from key-value pairs - but it's more efficient to use pairs than to zip two lists togther (because it avoids throwing away some elements if the lists are of different length):

```
from hypothesis import given, strategies as st


@given(
    st.lists(
        st.tuples(
            st.text(min_size=1, max_size=10),
            st.from_type(type).flatmap(st.from_type).filter(lambda x: x is not None),
        ),
        min_size=2,
        unique_by=(lambda kv: kv[0], lambda kv: type(kv[1])),
    ).map(dict)
)
def test_something(dictionary):
    values_types = list(map(type, dictionary.values()))
    assert len(set(values_types)) == len(values_types)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems very equivalent to Azat's in terms of invalid examples (up to 25/30), but runs a bit slower (up to 28 ms:
```
- 100 passing examples, 0 failing examples, 28 invalid examples
  - Typical runtimes: 0-28 ms
  - Fraction of time spent in data generation: ~ 98%
  - Stopped because settings.max_examples=100
  - Events:
    * 64.84%, Retried draw from sampled_from
```

Comment: It's running slightly slower because it is much more likely to generate large dictionaries.